# How to run a .cpp file by xcode without adding it to a project?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I am trying to run my old .cpp files with double clicking on them to get opened by xcode. But when the code opens in the xcode editor no Run option exists. I tried to wrap my head around it and the only solution I found is to create a new project and then adding this file to that. What should I do?

Comment: In xcode it is Run which should be equivalent of compile.

Comment: Either create an Xcode project or if they are self-contained .cpp files you could create a `Makefile` to compile them from the command line.

Comment: No, Run as in "run project".  Compiling the source file is part of that process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run a .cpp file by Xcode without adding it to a project.

if you want to run a .cpp file without creating a project.You can just use terminal and find the directory of your file,enter:
g++ a.cpp

Comment: Annoying.   For quick run and go, try CodeRunner.  Way fewer features than Xcode or most editors (like VS Code) or IDEs but really simple for experimenting.